# User Sign up and retrieval of all user data app in android with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication

I am a newbie in Android Development, I want to build an app where user from anywhere can register (Userdata should be save in sqlite db) and after registration n login process user can see all the other user list who are register.

Is this possible using android and sqlite db. I search many times on google but all i found tutorial for sqlite. I started to follow the tutorial but i am confuse as it is stated that Sqlite can only save APP data and private data of user. How could i make app for register user from anywhere. Suggestion and links for another method to do that is also helpful, Please Help 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use common sens ... it is not possible without centralized system

Comment: @Selvin I am a newbie i just want to know if sqlite can work as centralize database or not, If you know anything about android it doesn't mean everybody knows the same, may be you get some common sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SQLite** can save only data for specific user in the specific device of the user. No one can access **SQLite** database which is stored in my device from any other device. Such scenario can be implemented by centralized system where all the details are stored in **Mysql**, **mongo DB** or similar. These databases are stored in centralized system so that it can be accessed from anywhere by anyone as per authorization settings. It is accessed by the internet.

So as per your requirement go for centralized system where database can be used by using web services. **Web services** can interact with server in which database is stored and can give you desired output in form of **JSON** or **XML**.